# Search for a specific pattern in a hash map

Tags: java

I have the below snippet.I need to find out if there is any key in the map with pattern searching with discount.Help appreciate.

```
public class MapStringSearch {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map test = new HashMap();
        test.put("discount.1", 1);
        test.put("discount.2", 2);
        test.put("discount.3", 3);
        test.put("voucher.4", 4);

    }

}
```

Comment: You've shown an example (using a raw type, btw - not a good idea) of putting entries into a map, but you haven't explained what you're trying to achieve. What do you mean by "with pattern searching with discount"?

Comment: Hint: it would require the method `test.keySet()`, a for-loop to go through the keys, an if statement and some more code...

Comment: It is possible to do what you want to do... but not efficiently. Wanting to do this is... peculiar. As an approach to achieving what you really want to do it is probably flawed.

Comment: @Raedwald : May be I am wrong , but What I meant by my question is , suppose we have multiple  keys in the map , is there any API or any Patterns based key search which would just take the key as  input and return me the hash map, I just avoid to avoid iteration in my code if there exists an API.

Answer (score 1):

One of the way is :

```
for ( String key : test.keySet() ) {
    if(key.contains("discount"))
      // do something...
    else
      // do something...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Iterator it = test.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pairs.getKey().toLowerCase().contains("YourString"))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tend to do this way:

```
discount.put("1", 1);
discount.put("2", 2);
discount.put("3", 3);

test.put("discounts", discount);
```

So to find discounts:

```
test.get("discounts");
```

And after of this you can iterate with keyset (or entryset) or find concrete discounts with get...

You can iterate the keyset, sure, but honestly; I would redefine de data scheme of my application in order to not have "something.[0-9]" elements in a hashmap.

Answer (score 0):

I would use SortedMap instead of HashMap and check if `tailMap("discount").firstKey().stratsWith("discount")`